# CSS Column Definition List in Safari bug

Tags: css, safari

Having trouble getting this column layout to work in Safari.

Amazingly it works in IE11 & Edge.

Has anyone achieved something similar?

https://jsfiddle.net/gurtfrobe/3xhmxtx5/1/

Here's a sample code snippet to keep the SO validator happy.

```
<dt>.</dt>
<dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
<dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
<dt>A</dt>
<dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
<dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
<dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
<dt>B</dt>
<dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
<dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
```

Comment: Does it have to be a definition list (which I’d find rather questionable semantically to begin with here) …?

Comment: ..also define *"trouble"*

Comment: @CBroe - It doesn't have to be a <dl>, open to suggestions. I had initially tried a <ul> inside a <ol>.

Comment: @Paulie_D - "trouble" is with the <dt> elements hugging the left of the container, rather than lining up with their columns.

I was surprised it worked as much as it did when I tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with negative margins instead of `absolute` positioning.

I also swapped the `<dl>` for a `<ul>` inside a `<ol>`.

Updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gurtfrobe/Lz21cg1o/2/

Answer (score 0):

For safari it requires the vendor prefix: `-webkit-`. So you have to apply the css like below.

```
dl {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    columns: 100px 4;
    -webkit-columns: 100px 4; /* for safari browsers */
}
```

```css
 dl {
     font-size: 14px;
     line-height: 1.6;
      columns: 100px 4;
      -webkit-columns: 100px 4;
 }

 dt {
  font-weight: 700;
  left: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto; 
 }

 dd {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
 }
```

```html
<dl>
    <dt>.</dt>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dt>A</dt>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dt>B</dt>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dt>C</dt>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dt>D</dt>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dt>F</dt>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dt>G</dt>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dt>H</dt>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dt>I</dt>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dt>J</dt>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dt>L</dt>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dt>M</dt>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dt>N</dt>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dt>O</dt>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dt>P</dt>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dt>R</dt>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dt>S</dt>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
    <dt>T</dt>
    <dd><a href="#">Sample link</a></dd>
   </dl>
```